# How does #assign and #global variables scope works in ftl's?

Tags: freemarker, scripting-language

I am currently looking to figure the scope of #assign variable. However, scope seems to  be confusing please see following example and try to explain. I have some hypothesis which works but if somebody has concrete documentation, it will be very helpful.

```
<#assign test1 = a.test1/>
<#if some_condition>
    <#if a.test1?contains(",")>
        <#assign mylist = a.test1?split(",")/>
        <#assign test1 = mylist?size-1?int/>
    </#if>
    <!-- Line is giving me exception, if I convert everything to #global it works -->
    <#assign testing>${test1} SAJNF</#assign>
</#if>
```

Can somebody explain scope in #assign and #global?

Answer (score 2):

That example should work equally well with `#assign` and `#global`. You had some kind of oversight there.

As of `#assign` VS `#global`: Variables set via `#assign` are only visible from the template where they were assigned, plus in the templates that where `#include`-d in that template (or `#include`-d in an `#include`-d template, etc.), because `#include`-ing is pretty much like copy-pasting. But if you `#import` a template, as that will have its own namespace, it won't share `#assign`-ed variables with the `#import`-ing template. It will share the global variables with it though; variables set with `#global` are seen from every templates, just like the data-model. You should hardly ever use `#global` BTW.